# two separate portion in a page

Tags: php, html

I want to make two different portions for an image to be shown on the right side and some code on the left.

Here is the code that you'll understand seeing

```
<h2><?php echo $data['user'] ?> - Profile Page</h2>
<center><p id ="greet" align="left">Next Generation Gaming - <?php echo $title ?></p></center>
<p><center align="right"><img src='images/skins/<?php echo $data['SavSkin'] ?>.png' width="580" height"110"> </center></p>

<p id ="greet"><?php echo "Banned : ".$pban ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Money : <?php echo $data['money'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Banked : <?php echo $data['Bank'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Kills : <?php echo $data['kills'] ?></p>

<p class='text-alert' id ="greet">Kill Death Ratio : <?php
$kd = $data['kills'] / $data['deaths']; echo round($kd, 2); ?>
</p>

<p id ="greet">Admin Kills : <?php echo $data['AdminKills'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Cookies : <?php echo $data['cookies'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Cakes : <?php echo $data['cakes'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Biscuits : <?php echo $data['biscuits'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Icecreams : <?php echo $data['icecreams'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Race Won : <?php echo $data['RaceWon'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Quiz Won : <?php echo $data['ReactionTestWon'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Command Used : <?php echo $data['TotalCmdsUsed'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Total Warnings : <?php echo $data['TotalWarnings'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Total Logins : <?php echo $data['TotalLogins'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Registered Date : <?php echo $data['RegisteredDate'] ?></p>
<p id ="greet">Last Login : <?php echo $data['LastOnlineDate'] ?></p>
```

On the second like you could see that i have added an image

```
<p><center align="right"><img src='images/skins/<?php echo $data['SavSkin'] ?>.png' width="580" height"110"> </center></p>
```

What i was trying to do is make that image to be shown on the right side of the page and the rest of them to the left.
Through what way could it be possible?

Comment: Try using `div` instead of `center` tag

Comment: Yes, with CSS. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use some CSS

Rewrite

```
<p><center align="right"><img src='images/skins/<?php echo
 $data['SavSkin'] ?>.png' width="580" height"110"> </center></p>
```

as

```
<div style="float:right;"><img src="images/skins/<?php echo $data['SavSkin'] ?>.png" width="580" height"110" /></div>
```